# Use multinomial regression to create a scoring formula

Tags: r, regression, multinomial, nnet

I am trying to build a scoring model using a multinomial regression.

Some of this data is from a database, while the target value `unconditional` is from an assessment and has 3 potential modalities. I tried both multinomial and ordered logistic regression and found that multinomial was giving better results

I am aiming at building a score to use in my database that would help predicting `unconditional` for any new case registered in my database.

Below is a reproducible examples:

```
testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  dependency.cat <- c('Low dependency <30%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Low dependency <30%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Low dependency <30%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Low dependency <30%', 'Low dependency <30%', 'Low dependency <30%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'High dependency >60%', 'Average dependency 30-60%'),
  case.size <- c('Case size 1', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 3', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 3', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 1', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 3', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 3', 'Case size 1', 'Case size 1', 'Case size 1', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 2', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 6 or more', 'Case size 3', 'Case size 4-5', 'Case size 2'),
  gender <- c('Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male'),
  has.baby <- c('No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'),
  able.to.work <- c('Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'),
  arrivalyear <- c('2012', '2017', '2013', '2014', '2012', '2015', '2012', '2017', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2015', '2014', '2017', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2012', '2013', '2013', '2012', '2013', '2016', '2013', '2012', '2015', '2015', '2017', '2016', '2012', '2015', '2017', '2012', '2016', '2016', '2016', '2013'),
  unconditionnal <- c('OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NotOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'Average', 'NotOK', 'Average', 'OK', 'NotOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NotOK', 'NotOK', 'OK', 'Average', 'OK', 'OK', 'Average', 'OK', 'OK', 'NotOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK')))

names(testdata) <- c("dependency.cat" ,"case.size" ,"gender" ,"has.baby" ,"able.to.work" ,"arrivalyear" ,"unconditionnal")

library(nnet)
model <- multinom(unconditionnal ~ ., data = testdata, trace = FALSE)
testdata$unconditionnal.predicted <- predict(model, testdata)
testdata <- cbind(testdata, predict(model, testdata, type ="p"))
```

If this was a simple logistic regression, I could use a cut-off point and then use the intercept with the terms to build a scoring formula but here I am lost as I get on side the prediction `unconditionnal.predicted` and then on the other side 3 probabilities to be in each category `predict(model, testdata, type ="p")`.

How can I reverse engineer my multinomial regression in order to develop the scoring formula ?
that would look like...

```
score = dependency.cat --- case.size --- gender -- has.baby -- able.to.work -- arrivalyear  
   if score > X then OK
  if score < Z then NotOK
```

Maybe what I am thinking of is not making sense? If not what approach shall I used?

Thanks

I saw https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/how-to-find-cutoff-values-in-multinomial-regression but it did not helped me...

Comment: In a simple logistic regression you have a binary outcome, so the `probability of one outcome` is `1 - probability of the other outcome`. Why don't you group together `Average` and `NotOK` so you can transform your problem to a simple logistic regression one? Or you can follow exactly the same method (multinomial) and in the end you just keep the probability of `OK` and use a cutt-off point to predict `OK` or `Other`.

Comment: Can't you pick the highest prediction as the "winner". There could not be a single "score" for a three way possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the largest probability for each row and get their column names. Here is the code

```
library(nnet)
model <- multinom(unconditionnal ~ ., data = testdata, trace = FALSE)
p <- predict(model, type="probs", newdata = testdata[,-7])
table(testdata$unconditionnal,colnames(p)[apply(p,1,which.max)])
```

The result is pretty good

```
            Average NotOK OK
 Average       4     0  0
 NotOK         0     6  0
 OK            0     1 28
```

Hope it helps.

Best.